# Wireless internet

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have a laptop, Lenovo G560, and I'm unable to connect to any wireless networks.
It says that I need to turn on the wireless by pressing some button on the keyboard, but I don't have any buttons for turning on and off wireless. OS is Win 7.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Download your user guide from the lenovo support site...http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/default.page

Comment: I'm not super familiar with IdeaPads, but it's either a Fn key combination or a physical switch on the side of the system.

Comment: Is the wireless switch turned off? Its located on the side or front of your laptop.

Comment: There is no switch for wireless.

Comment: According to the [user's guide](http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User's%20guides%20and%20manuals/G460-G560/G460&G560%20UserGuide%20V1.0%20EN%20147002899-1.1%20(10.03.18)_web.pdf), the wireless switch should be at the front, to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and press <kbd>F5</kbd>. This should enable/disable your wireless adapter.

Comment: Didn't help. Nothing changes, I troubleshooted it again, it says "wireless capability is turned off".

Comment: @MladenB Check the driver status. What does it say?

Comment: I have only one driver missing, "unknown device". Network adapters seem to work fine.

Comment: Try this: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G560-Unable-to-switch-on-WLAN-or-Bluetooth/ta-p/370149